# SwiftyJSON in Watchkit Extension not working

Tags: ios, json, cocoapods, watchkit

Using iOS-9.2, watchOS-2.1, Swift-2.1.1 under XCode-7.2:

Trying to use SwiftyJSON (v2.3.2) inside my Watchkit Extension! The install of the SwiftyJSON was done by the following podfile:

podfile:

```
xcodeproj 'TableTestKOS001.xcodeproj'
workspace 'TableTestKOS001.xcworkspace'
platform :ios, '9.0'
inhibit_all_warnings!

use_frameworks!
link_with 'TableTestKOS001', 'TableTestKOS001 WatchKit Extension'

def shared_pods
      pod 'SwiftyJSON', :git => 'https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON.git'
end

target 'TableTestKOS001' do
    shared_pods
end

target 'TableTestKOS001Tests' do
    shared_pods
end

target 'TableTestKOS001 WatchKit Extension' do
    platform :ios, '9.0'
    shared_pods
end
```

Using "pod install", I get:

```
Updating local specs repositories
Analyzing dependencies
Pre-downloading: `SwiftyJSON` from `https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON.git`
Downloading dependencies
Installing SwiftyJSON (2.3.2)
Generating Pods project
Integrating client project

[!] Please close any current Xcode sessions and use `TableTestKOS001.xcworkspace` for this project from now on.
Sending stats
Sending stats
Sending stats
Pod installation complete! There is 1 dependency from the Podfile and 1 total
pod installed.
```

That tells me, that so far everything is ok !

After that I open the project (not with the .proj-file) but with the newly created workspace-File (i.e. in my case TableTestKOS001.xcworkspace).

Now the problems start:

As soon as I "import SwiftyJSON" into any of my WatchKit-Extension's WKInterfaceControllers, I get the following error (i.e. "No such module SwiftyJSON")

[image]

And moreover, next to the above error, I get the following warning :

[image]

Can anybody help with this ??
Any support is appreciated !!

P.S. The same error and warning occur also when I am importing SwiftyJSON to any of the iOS-target's ViewControllers...

Answer (score 4):

I managed to get it fixed by:
- Updating cocoapods then modifying the `Podfile` to specify the platform

```
target 'My App' do
    pod 'Google/Analytics'
    pod 'SwiftyJSON', :git => 'https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON.git'
end

target 'My App Watch Extension' do
    platform :watchos, '2.0'
    pod 'SwiftyJSON', :git => 'https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON.git'
end
```

- Then run `pod install` again
- Finally, clear project data by clicking window -> projects -> "Select your project" and Delete the Derived Data

Comment: Thank you very much - I will give it a try !